# When is memset to 0 nonportable?

Tags: c, portability, memset

From [this comment in GCC bug #53119](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53119#c0):

> In C, `{0}` is the universal zero initializer equivalent to C++'s `{}` (the latter being invalid in C). It is necessary to use whenever you want a zero-initialized object of a complete but conceptually-opaque or implementation-defined type. The classic example in the C standard library is `mbstate_t`:
>
> ```
> mbstate_t state = { 0 }; /* correctly zero-initialized */
> ```
>
> versus the common but nonportable:
>
> ```
> mbstate_t state;
> memset(&state, 0, sizeof state);
> ```

It strikes me as odd that the latter version could be unportable (even for implementation-defined types, the compiler has to know the size). What is the issue here and when is a `memset(x, 0, sizeof x)` unportable?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`memset(p, 0, n)` sets to all-bits-0.
An initializer of `{ 0 }` sets to the *value* 0.
On just about any machine you've ever heard of, the two concepts are equivalent.

However, there have been machines where the floating-point value 0.0 was *not* represented by a bit pattern of all-bits-0.  And there have been machines where a null pointer was not represented by a bit pattern of all-bits-0, either.  On those machines, an initializer of `{ 0 }` would always get you the zero initialization you wanted, while `memset` might not.

See also [question 7.31](http://c-faq.com/malloc/calloc.html) and [question 5.17](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

---

Postscript: One other difference, as pointed out by @ryker: `memset` will set any "holes" in a padded structure to 0, while setting that structure to `{ 0 }` might not.

Comment: I was about to write the same. I was working on the soviet computer where float numbers with all words set to zero was a trap representation :)

Comment: It used to puzzle me that all-bits-0 could ever not be the floating-point value 0.0.  But once you learn how floating-point values work inside, typically using an offset representation for the signed exponent, it's kind of surprising that all-bits-0 *does* represent 0.0, since an exponent value of 0 is typically represented as the biased form `0x80` or `0x400`.  (But of course in IEEE-754 0.0 is *not* stored with an actual exponent value of 0, so it works out.)

Comment: Old computers were not using modern datatypes :). On that one, all zero was an indication of the memory subsystem failure. Any zero read from memory was rasing hardware exception.

Comment: _Classic_ may not be apropos, but because of the variability of how `mbstate_t` can be defined, it is a _good_ example.

Comment: Could you name these machines, please?

Comment: @ThomasWeller For nonzero pointer examples, see [question 5.17](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).  I don't have any names to hand of machines that had nonzero representations of floating-point 0.0, but I have it on good authority they existed.

Comment: The standard 32-bit and 64-bit floating point formats are laid out so that the represented number is a monotonic function of the bit representation interpreted as an integer (aside from the sign bit). From that perspective it isn't surprising that 0.0 is represented by 000...000. In formats like x87 80-bit floating point where the leading digit of the mantissa is stored explicitly, you just need the mantissa to be zero and the exponent to be anything other than the special infinity/NaN value, so again it's not surprising that 000...000 represents 0.0.

Comment: @benrg Good point about monotonicity.  Yet another way of looking at it is that 0.0 sits very nicely among the subnormals, where it surely belongs, because it obviously doesn't have an implicit "1" bit, either.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this has to do with how types are represented.

Section 6.7.9p10 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) describes how fields are initialized as follows:

> If  an  object  that  has  automatic  storage  duration  is  not
> initialized  explicitly, its  value  is indeterminate. If an  object
> that  has  static  or  thread  storage  duration  is  not  initialized
>
> explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>   to zero bits

And p21 also states:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
> are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
> string literal used to initialize an array of known
> size  than  there  are  elements  in  the  array, the  remainder  of
> the  aggregate  shall  be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
> duration

The difference between this and setting all bytes to zero is that some of the above values may not necessarily be represented by all bits zero.

For example, there are some architectures where the address 0 is a valid address.  This means that a null pointer is not represented as all bits zero.  (Note: `(void *)0` is specified as a null pointer constant by the standard, however the implementation will treat this as whatever the representation of a null pointer is)

The standard also doesn't mandate a particular representation for floating point types.  While the most common representation, IEEE754, does use all bits 0 to represent the value +0, this is not necessarily true for other representations.

Comment: "that a NULL pointer " better as "that a _null pointer_" (lower case).  The _null pointer constant_ `NULL` carries it set of difficulties.   `NULL` may be `int` 0, yet a _null pointer_ may differ from all zero bits.

Answer (score 1):

Noting a difference in behavior between the two methods...

In `...= {0};` if padding bytes exist, they will not be cleared.
But a call to `memset()` will clear padding.

From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstate_t)

> "Possible implementation of mbstate_t is a struct type holding an array representing the incomplete multibyte character, an integer
> counter indicating the number of bytes in the array that have been
> processed, and a representation of the current shift state."

In the case `mbstate_t` *is* implemented as a `struct` it is notable that  `{0}` will not set padding bytes that may exist to `zero`, making the following assumption debatable:

```
mbstate_t state = { 0 }; /* correctly zero-initialized */
```

`memset()` however does include padding bytes.

```
memset(state , 0, sizeof state);//all bytes in memory region of test will be cleared
```